# Conditionally display button on Table depending on number of visible rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form which allows the user to add a new table row via a button in the bottom row which all is working well and also allows users to delete a table row but will always leave one row visible. You can see a working example of this at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/wnSfa/1/).

I now need to make one change to how the Delete button appears. Currently it doesn't appear when there is one row, but when you add a row it appears for all rows except the last row. I need to change it using the following rules:

(i) if there is only one row the delete button should not appear
(ii) if there are 2 rows the delete button should appear on all rows, but if one row is delete rule (i) applies and there should be no delete button again
(iii) if there are 3 rows the delete button should appear on all rows, but if they delete 2 rows then rule (i) applies

and so on.

I'm hiding the delete button on the first row as follows:

```
<td>
            <input type="button" class="button mt5 delbtn" value="Delete" id="deleteRowButton" name="deleteRowButton" style="display: none"/>
        </td>
```

and here's the script that runs when new rows are added/deleted:

```
$('#lastYear').on('click', '.delbtn', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});

var newIDSuffix = 2;
$('#lastYear').on('click', '.addbtn', function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    $(thisRow).find('.delbtn').show();

    var cloned = $(thisRow).clone();
    cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.substring(0, id.length - 1) + newIDSuffix;
        $(this).attr('id', id);
    });

    cloned.insertAfter(thisRow).find('input:text').val('');
    cloned.find('.delbtn').hide();
    cloned.find("[id^=lastYearSelect]")
    .autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function (e, ui) {

            $(e.target).val(ui.item.value);
            setDropDown.call($(e.target));
        }
    }).change(setDropDown);

    $(this).remove();
    newIDSuffix++;
});
```

I'm completely stumped at this point - appreciate any solutions to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i have updated your code. Now its working at fiddle.

```
$('#lastYear').on('click', '.delbtn', function () {
      var tableRef=$(this).parent("td").parent("tr").parent("tbody");
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      if( tableRef.find("tr").length==3){
        tableRef.find("tr").find("input.addbtn").show();
        tableRef.find("tr").find("input.delbtn").hide();
      }else{
        tableRef.find("tr:last").find("input.addbtn").show();
      }
});

  var newIDSuffix = 2;
  $('#lastYear').on('click', '.addbtn', function () {
      var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
      $(thisRow).find('.delbtn').show();

      var cloned = $(thisRow).clone();
      cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         id = id.substring(0, id.length - 1) + newIDSuffix;
         $(this).attr('id', id);
      });

     cloned.insertAfter(thisRow).find('input:text').val('');
     cloned.find('.delbtn').show();
     cloned.find("[id^=lastYearSelect]")
    .autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function (e, ui) {

            $(e.target).val(ui.item.value);
            setDropDown.call($(e.target));
        }
    }).change(setDropDown);

    $(this).hide();
    newIDSuffix++;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/wnSfa/7/
This will apply the 3 rules told by you.

I did changes in

```
$('#lastYear').on('click', '.delbtn', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        if ($("#lastYear tr").length < 4){
            $('.delbtn').hide();
        }
    });



cloned.insertAfter(thisRow).find('input:text').val('');
        if ($("#lastYear tr").length < 2){
            cloned.find('.delbtn').hide();
        }
```

Note: But if you delete the "last row" Which has "Add another activity" button,  you can't add any other rows. You didn't mention user can delete the last or not so i didn't do anything for that. Let me know your comments.

Comment: Thanks that works well - we do need to keep at least one table row at all times which shows the "add another activity button". Sorry I didn't make that obvious in my original post.